# create arrays of intersecting values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Here are some arrays of values:

```
values = [
  [1,2,3],
  [2,3,4],
  [8,9,10],
  [9,10,11],
  [13,14,15]
];
```

I want to create new numerically sorted arrays of the union of arrays' values when there is an intersection of the values of two or more arrays.

Values in these new sorted arrays will be unique.

If an array does not intersect any other arrays, then we include that array in the results (e.g. `[13,14,15]` in the example).

For example:

```
clusters = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [8,9,10,11],
  [13,14,15]
];
```

Since value[0] and value[1] intersect, we add a union of their values to clusters.

Since value [2] and value[3] intersect, we add a union of their values to clusters.

Since value[4] does not intersect value[0] through value[4], we just add value[5] to clusters.

---

Now, if there was a `value[6] = [3, 100]`, then our clusters would look like this:

```
clusters = [
  [1,2,3,4,100],
  [8,9,10,11],
  [13,14,15]
];
```

because value[6] intersected value[0] and value[1], so we add to their union.

Is there a technique or optimal way to do this?

In my example, the original arrays are sorted, but that might not necessarily be the case.

Comment: Is `[2, 3, 4, 1]` an acceptable result for `clusters[0]`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon clusters should be sorted, I will clarify the OP

Comment: What if two arrays contain `[2, 1]` and `[1, 3]`? Should the merged array be `[2, 1, 3]` or `[1, 2, 3]`? “Sorted” in terms of numerical sort or based on the original arrays?

Comment: @SebastianSimon numerical sort of the values, so [1,2,3]

Comment: I almost have a working _O_ (_n_ log _n_) algorithm (single pass through all elements and a subsequent sort), but it doesn’t produce a final result in cases like `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]`: `Array.from(new Set(values.reduce((r, a) => { a.forEach((e) => { if(r.has(a)){ r.get(a).push(e); } else if(r.has(e)){ r.set(a, r.get(e)).get(e).push(e); } else{ r.set(e, a); } }); return r; }, new Map()).values()), (a) => Array.from(new Set(a)).sort((a, b) => a - b));`.

Comment: Basic idea: a map containing { _elem_ → _subArray_ } but also { _subArray_ → _canonicalArray_ }. Iterate all elements of all sub arrays. If { _subArray_ → _canonicalArray_ } exists, push the current element to _canonicalArray_; else if { _elem_ → _subArray_ } exists, create a mapping from the current sub array to _subArray_ and push the current element to that _subArray_; else create a new mapping from the current element to the current sub array. Only the map _values_ (right-hand side of “→”) are then considered for the result, which must be deduplicated internally and externally (2× `Set`).

Comment: @SebastianSimon  I would put this down as an answer, and just mention the issue, I'm sure it still would be useful for others to see.   This is one of those problems were single pass might not be possible, as every element needs to compare to every element.

Comment: You should remove the lodash tag.

Comment: It really doesn’t seem possible in a single pass. You end up with redundant mappings, e.g. when `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]` is passed, this map is created: { 1 → _A_, 2 → _A_, 3 → _B_, 4 → _B, C → A_, (_C → A_) }, and _A_ ends up as `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` and _B_ ends up as `[ 3, 4 ]`, but you’d need to “unset” `3` and `4` in the map in order to remove _B_ from the result. As the final `3` is passed, it is distinctly the case that the current element and the current sub array do not map to the same object; this could be used for a `runAgain = true;` flag to use the algorithm recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an edited snippet in response to the comments using [`.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), seeding the accumulator with a copy of the passed array, and still using `some()` and `includes()` to find duplicates.

`reduceRight()` iterates the array in reverse, while `findIndex()` searches from the beginning. When a match is found the current iterated array is pushed to the matched array and then the current element is removed from the accumulator using `splice()`.

```js
function clusterDuplicates(arr) {
  return arr
    .reduceRight((a, arr, i) => {
      if (i) {
        let j = a.slice(0, i).findIndex(_arr => arr.some(x => _arr.includes(x)));

        if (~j) {
          a[j].push(...arr);
          a.splice(i, 1);
        }

      }
      return a
    }, [...arr])
    .map(arr => [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => a - b));
}

console.log(clusterDuplicates([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [8, 9, 10], [9, 11, 10], [14, 13, 15]]));
console.log(clusterDuplicates([[1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 3]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Original Answer**

*As noted in the comments, this fails to look ahead for duplicates.*

Here's a fairly concise implementation using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) looking for intersections using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). The result is then mapped to remove duplicates using `Set`s and then sorted.

```js
const
  values = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 2], [8, 9, 10], [9, 11, 10], [14, 13, 15]],
  result =
    values
      .reduce((a, arr) => {
        let i = a.findIndex(_arr => arr.some(x => _arr.includes(x)));

        if (i === -1) {
          i = a.push([]) - 1;
        }

        a[i].push(...arr);

        return a
      }, [])
      .map(arr => [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => a - b));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if 2 arrays intersect, a nice an simple way is to compare the set of both arrays together's size, with each array's set size, and if there different we know they intersect.

Below is an example..

```js
const values = [
  [1,2,3],
  [8,9,10],
  [2,3,4],
  [9,10,11],
  [13,14,15]
];

function arrayItersect(a,b) {
  return new Set([...a,...b]).size !==
    new Set(a).size + new Set(b).size;
}

function joinIntersections(v) {
  const a = [...v]; //make a copy
  for (let l = 0; l < a.length-1; l += 1) {
    let l2 = l + 1;
    while (l2 < a.length) {
      if (arrayItersect(a[l], a[l2])) {
        a[l] = 
          [...new Set(
          [...a[l],...a.splice(l2, 1)[0]]
          )];
      } else l2 ++;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(joinIntersections(values));
```

Comment: @SebastianSimon   Yeah, not 100% sure what the OP means by intersection here,..  Looking closer at the output I assume the OP means keep consecutive values together.  I've updated to do this instead.

Comment: apologies, i have updated the OP to clarify

Comment: @jedierikb   Ah right, that now makes sense... I've updated my answer..

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Yes, it could be optimised here, took the easy route out of just iterating if arrays get joined.  If the dataset for this is likely to be large, I would definitely consider optimising.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  I've updated to use a while loop & remove the itteration, that should reduce the time complexity a tad.

Comment: Same problem here: `[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]` is being split into `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]`, but calling it another time on the result merges it into the expected `[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for-loop` and for each sub array check with previous array (last) whether it has intersection. If intersection, add the merged array to result.

```js
values = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3, 4],
  [8, 9, 10],
  [9, 10, 11],
  [13, 14, 15],
];

const intersect = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const both = [...arr1, ...arr2];
  const uniq = [...new Set(both)];
  return uniq.length !== both.length ? uniq : null;
};

const compact =  (arrArr) => {
  if (arrArr?.length < 2) {
    return arrArr;
  }
  const res = [];
  let last = arrArr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arrArr.length; i++) {
    last = intersect(last, arrArr[i]) ?? (res.push(last), arrArr[i]);
  }
  res.push(last);
  return res;
};

console.log(compact(values))
```